# Minimizing the distance of pairing points

Tags: algorithm, matrix, hungarian-algorithm

My problem is as follows:

```
Given a number of 2n points, I can calculate the distance between all points 
and get a symmetrical matrix.

Can you create n pairs of points, so that the sum of the distance of all pairs is 
minimal?

EDIT: Every point has to be in one of the pairs. Which means that
every point is only allowed to be in one pair.
```

I have naively tried to use the Hungarian algorithm and hoped that it may give me an assignment, so that the assignments are symmetrical. But that obviously did not work, as I do not have a bipartite graph.

After a search, I found the [Stable roommates problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem), which seems to be similar to my problem, but the difference is, that it just tries to find a matching, but not to try to minimize some kind of distance.

Does anyone know a similar problem or even a solution? Did I miss something? The problem does actually not seem that difficult, but I just could not come up with an optimal solution.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you have a symmetrical matrix containing the distance between every point? Why not turn that matrix into a set sorted by distance [start_point,end_point,distance] and pick the first n pairs?

Comment: Every point is only allowed to be in one pair. This is not guaranteed, if I only sort by distance. I should add this to the problem description.

Comment: Hmm, that does make it more difficult. However, are you sure the Hungarian Algorithm won't work? Instead of viewing it as a complete undirected graph, split each point into two points (a source and a destination), and view it as a complete bipartite directed graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a primal-dual algorithm due to Edmonds (the Blossom algorithm), which you really don't want to implement yourself if possible. Vladimir Kolmogorov has an [implementation](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html) that may be suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try network-flow. The max flow is the number of the pairs you want to create. And calculate the min cost of it.

Answer (score 0):

now this isn't a guarantee but just a hunch.

you can find the shortest pair, match them, and remove it from the set.

and recurse until you have no pairs left.

It is clearly sub-optimal. but I have a hunch that the ratio of just how sub-optimal this is to the absolutely optimal solution can be bounded. The hope is to use some sub-modularity argument and bound it to something like (1 - 1 / e) fraction of the global optimal, but I wasn't able to do it. Maybe someone could take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a C++ memoization implementation in Competitive Programming 3 as follows (note maximum of N was 8):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int N, target;
double dist[20][20], memo[1<<16];

double matching(int bitmask)
{
    if (memo[bitmask] > -0.5)    // Already computed? Then return the result if yes
        return memo[bitmask];
    if (bitmask == target)       // If all students are already matched then cost is zero
        return memo[bitmask] = 0;

    double ans = 2000000000.0;        // Infinity could also work
    int p1, p2;

    for (p1 = 0; p1 < 2*N; ++p1)      // Find first non-matched point
        if (!(bitmask & (1 << p1)))
            break;
    for (p2 = p1 + 1; p2 < 2*N; ++p2) // and pair it with another non-matched point
        if (!(bitmask & (1 << p2)))
            ans = min(ans, dist[p1][p2]+matching(bitmask| (1 << p1) | (1 << p2)));

    return memo[bitmask] = ans;

}
```

and then the main method (driving code)

```
int main()
{
    int i,j, caseNo = 1, x[20], y[20];

    while(scanf("%d", &N), N){
         for (i = 0; i < 2 * N; ++i)
             scanf("%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);
         for (i = 0; i < 2*N - 1; ++i)
             for (j = i + 1; j < 2*N; ++j)
                  dist[i][j] = dist[j][i] = hypot(x[i]-x[j], y[i]-y[j]);

         // use DP to solve min weighted perfect matching on small general graph
         for (i = 0; i < (1 << 16); ++i) memo[i] = -1;
         target = (1 << (2 * N)) - 1;
         printf("Case %d: %.2lf", caseNo++, matching(0));

    }
    return 0;

}
```